# How to disable animation in TableView selection in Popover?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, uipopovercontroller

I have a popover that appears when I click on a cell. In this popover, there is a TableView with a row. When I click on that row, there is three new rows that appears with an animation. I would like to remove that animation. Is it possible ?

Here is my code :

```
extension PlanningActionTableViewController
{
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return numberOfRows()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ActionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!PlanningActionCell


        // Info cells
        if registration == nil
        {
            if slot.registrations.count > indexPath.row
            {
                let contact = slot.registrations[indexPath.row].contact
                let name = contact.lastname + " " + contact.firstname
                cell.actionLabel.text = (name.characters.count > 1 ? name : "Réservation en cours")
                cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
                cell.imageSymbol.image = UIImage(named: "picto.user.default")

                return cell
            }

            cell.actionLabel.text = "Ajouter"
            cell.accessoryType = .None
            cell.imageSymbol.image = UIImage(named: "picto.user.add")

            return cell

        }

        // Actions cell
        switch indexPath.row
        {
        case 0:
            cell.actionLabel.text = "Détails"
            cell.accessoryType = .None
            cell.imageSymbol.image = UIImage(named: "picto.user.details")

        case 1:
            var state = "Non"
            if let contact = registration?.contact
            {
                state = (contact.isArrived ? "Oui" : "Non")
            }

            cell.actionLabel.text = "Est arrivé: " + state
            cell.accessoryType = .None
            cell.imageSymbol.image = UIImage(named: "picto.user.valid")

        default:
            cell.actionLabel.text = "Supprimer booking"
            cell.actionLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            cell.imageSymbol.image = UIImage(named: "picto.user.delete")
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

NumberOfRows :

```
func numberOfRows() -> Int
{
    if registration == nil
    {
        return slot.subslotsCount
    }

    return 3
}
```

Example in  video :

```html
<iframe src="//gifs.com/embed/1wvE6R" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width='480' height='220.7665505226481' style="-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;-webkit-transform: scale(1);" ></iframe>
```

Comment: First of all, what kind of animation do you mean, expanding the popover or appearance of the new rows, or both ? Secondly, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method itself is not responsible for rows animation, add the code where you extend the datasource, i.e. insert the new rows and/or alter the value of `numberOfRows`.

Comment: It is the appearance of the new rows. When I show that three lines (or more), there is an animation of the popover that is increasing downward.

Comment: If you don't want the animation, calculate the content size for the popover that you want, set it manually and trigger datasource update without animations.

Comment: There is no other way ? I put an example in video. It should be strange that there is not an option to execute it just without animation, or simply  by changing the animation ?

Comment: I think that it looks rather nice *with* the animation.

Comment: Yep, but it is my customer that decides ;)

Comment: Ah, there is that. Also, +1 for a very well-stated question, complete with code snippets and a video. I wish that all SO questions could be like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your viewDidLoad, set animations to false:

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
```

Comment: Note that this will disable *all* animations that are performed via `UIView` static calls, which probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a (now-deprecated) `UIPopoverController`? If so, you can call `setPopoverContentSize(_ size: CGSize, animated animated: Bool)` on it, passing in `false` for the `animated` argument, of course. Just calculate the size that the table would be with three rows.

If you're using a regular `UIViewController` with a modal presentation style, then you can set the content's size to that calculated table size.

Comment: mmm ok I will check that. Thank you :D